# check XML syntax with xmllint

Tags: xml

I am having a problem with some XML print files where the source system omits to convert some characters to their XML syntax equivalent (e.g. & is not converted to `&amp;`).

Is there a way to catch this with xmllint? (I don't need to check the general tree structure using XSD).

Answer (score 101):

```
xmllint --noout your_test_file.xml
```

Check for return code of this command. See [documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html#Error%20Return%20Codes). Value of `1` is returned when basic parsing errors are met. E.g.:

```
echo $?
```

or `echo %errorlevel%` if on Windows.

Comment: Why have the `--valid` flag if you don't have a DTD?

Comment: @YzmirRamirez Thanks, it shouldn't be there. I corrected my answer.

Comment: // , An easy way to check the return code follows: `$ xmllint --noout your_test_file.xml; echo $?`.

Comment: i use this command to test multiple files `xmllint --noout *.xml && echo ok || echo problem `

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, because there is a *TON* of XML out in the wild that was written by others, that doesn't have a formal DTD, but works perfectly fine and has a "self evident" structure.  As an example, I am working on a problem that requires processing 125 xml files containing 9855 lines from the FreePBX module library.  The first thing I wanted to do was to check to see that they are all validly formed XML.  That's what brought me here.  :-)

Comment: `echo %errorlevel%` on Windows

Answer (score 10):

I want to escalate @nathan-basanese's comment as the actual best answer to the OP's question:

> // , An easy way to check the return code follows: `$ xmllint --noout your_test_file.xml; echo $?`.
> – Nathan Basanese Nov 19 '15 at 0:38

By default xmllint "checks to determine if the document is well-formed".  So, `xmllint --noout --nonet goodfoo.xml` will be comletely silent with an exit code of 0 for well-formed XML while `xmllint --noout --nonet badfoo.xml` will emit an error message for each error and an exit code between 1 and 9 depending on the specific error.

The --nonet option tells xmllint *not* to fetch DTDs since it sounds like the OP just wants to scan for XML well-formedness.

Here's what I think she was looking for:

```
xmllint --noout --nonet /path/to/xmlfiles/*.xml 2>&1
```

That will generate a grep-able list of all errors and an exit code between 1 and 9 if there are any errors.

It will exit silently with an exit code of 0 if there are no errors in any of the scanned files.

Comment: Find the 9 different [error messages](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/xmllint.html)!

Answer (score 6):

```
xmllint --valid --encode utf-8 TEST.xml
```

will validate and output TEST.xml in utf-8

```
cat TEST.xml
```

<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE JM SYSTEM "mydtd">

<JM>
.
.
.
</JM>

Comment: // , Shouldn't you remove `--valid`?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to check validity(correctness) of any xml document using xmllint, here is one more way.

```
if xmllint --noout /tmp/test.xml > /dev/null 2>&1;
then
    echo "correct"
else
    echo "incorrect"
fi
```

Comment: You need to add `--valid` option to check validity.