# Report XML parsing issues with sonarqube

Tags: xml, sonarqube

we want to use sonarqube for code quality reviews on XML files.

We have setup a sonarqube server, added the xml plugin and run sonar runner over the example XML file.

Versions:
sonarqube-5.4
XML plugin v 1.4.1

Adding a tab into the sample xml file results (with active "Tab rule") in a warning which can be seen on the sonarqube web site.

When I corrupt the XML file, by removing the closing tag

```
<!---</sonar-config>-->.
```

Results in an error message of the sonar runner log:

INFO: Unable to anayle file C:/Build automation/sonar-examples-master/projects/l
anguages/xml/xml-sonar-runner/src/sonar_backup.xml
INFO: Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 233; columnNumber: 24; X
ML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
INFO: Sensor XmlSensor (done) | time=250ms
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
ERROR: Unable to parse xml file: C:\Build automation\sonar-examples-master\proje
cts\languages\xml\xml-sonar-runner\src\sonar_backup.xml

As a result the added Tab and the missing closing statement is not reported in the sonar web interface, the corrupted xml is just skipped witout an notice.

Can anyone give me support on this?
We need corrupted XML files being reported by sonar in the web interface.

So far, I could not find information on this problem in the forum.

Thanks and Regards
Martin

Here is a copy of the corrpted XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sonar-config>
    <version><![CDATA[321]]></version>
  <date><![CDATA[2012-08-08]]></date>
  <metrics/>
  <properties>
    <property>
      <key><![CDATA[java.vm.version]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[20.0-b12]]></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <key><![CDATA[wrapper.jvm.port.max]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[31999]]></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <key><![CDATA[java.vendor.url]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[http://java.sun.com/]]></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <key><![CDATA[JAVA_HOME]]></key>
      <value><![CDATA[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27]]></value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <name><![CDATA[Sonar way]]></name>
      <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
      <default-profile><![CDATA[true]]></default-profile>
      <provided><![CDATA[true]]></provided>
      <enabled><![CDATA[true]]></enabled>
      <used><![CDATA[false]]></used>
      <language><![CDATA[web]]></language>
      <active-rules>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[AvoidHtmlCommentCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[DynamicJspIncludeCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[CRITICAL]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[IllegalTagLibsCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[CRITICAL]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[tagLibs]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[InlineStyleCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[InternationalizationCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[attributes]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[outputLabel.value, outputText.value]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[JspScriptletCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[CRITICAL]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[LibraryDependencyCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[CRITICAL]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[libraries]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[java.sql,javax.sql]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[LongJavaScriptCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[CRITICAL]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[maxLines]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[5]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[MultiplePageDirectivesCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[WhiteSpaceAroundCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[FileLengthCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[maxLength]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[500]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[ComplexityCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[tags]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[catch, choose, if, forEach, forTokens,when]]></value>
            </param>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[operators]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[&&, ||, and,or]]></value>
            </param>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[max]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[12]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[DocTypeCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[dtd]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[DoubleQuotesCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[IllegalAttributeCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MAJOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[attributes]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[CAPTION.align, IFRAME.align, IMG.align, INPUT.align, OBJECT.align,
            LEGEND.align, TABLE.align, HR.align,
            DIV.align, H1.align, H2.align, H3.align, H4.align, H5.align, H6.align, P.align,
            alink, background, bgcolor,
            IMG.border, OBJECT.border, clear, color, compact, face, hspace, TD.height, TH.height,
            language, link,
            noshade, nowrap, HR.size, FONT.size, start, text, LI.type, OL.type, UL.type, LI.value,
            version,
            HR.width,
            PRE.width, TD.width, TH.width]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[IllegalElementCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MAJOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[elements]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[applet, basefont, center, dir, font, isindex, menu, s, strike, u]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[IllegalTabCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[MaxLineLengthCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[maxLength]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[120]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[RequiredAttributeCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MAJOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[attributes]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[img.alt,script.type]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
          <key><![CDATA[UnclosedTagCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MINOR]]></level>
          <params>
            <param>
              <key><![CDATA[ignoreTags]]></key>
              <value><![CDATA[verbatim]]></value>
            </param>
          </params>
        </active-rule>
        <active-rule>
            <key><![CDATA[AvoidCommentedOutCodeCheck]]></key>
          <plugin><![CDATA[Web]]></plugin>
          <level><![CDATA[MAJOR]]></level>
        </active-rule>
      </active-rules>
      <alerts/>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <rules/>
<!---</sonar-config>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube has a generic rule for `Parsing Error` ([RSPEC-2260](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2260)) but apparently the XML Plugin doesn't implement it.

Frankly, having a corrupt XML file is so bad that you shouldn't even proceed with the SonarQube analysis if that's the case. Why ? Because even if the `Parsing Error` rules was available for XML, it would screw up your metrics and related history (XML file has *x* issues, then all of the sudden only one because it can't be parsed, then *x* issues again once you fix it).

[Fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast): before anything, validate your XML files with `xmllint` for example (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622995/check-xml-syntax-with-xmllint)). If there's a corrupt one, there's not much point going any further.